# comparing 2 columns and matches assigned 3rd column value in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I've tried a few suggestions from searched results but nothing worked out as expected. I have a sheet of data where I need to do the following:

```
   COLUMN C.            COLUMN M                COLUMN N
======================================================
2  _4m_GazYOsE           _yi4N5b9sTU            $1000.00
3. _yi4N5b9sTU           -07npl8Y92c            $99.89
4  _8743yhFTsI           _92UI76VsTU            $3299.34
5  -07npl8Y92c           -wnNVaNYHs9            $879.23
```

Column C is the column I need to align the values of column N with. So I need to match column M with column C so that the values of Column N align correctly. Column C does not contain all values of column M so I cannot just sort column M to match column C sorted. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Tried a few suggestions with this being the last approach:

```
=VLOOKUP(C2, M2:N9000, 2, FALSE)
```

SAMPLE DATA

```
  COLUMN C.   COLUMN M   COLUMN N
======================================================
_4M_GazYOsE _4M_GazYOsE 1594272884
_5wLnJzVBKM _9v6tanouMs 1517322850
_9v6tanouMs _Jjc8dea6jw 1572620897
_Jjc8dea6jw _KyUswjq448 1662964205
_KLYRSiRuME _mrBY_QGjXw 1650433881
_KyUswjq448 _NVz9nI7tf0 1650374102
_mrBY_QGjXw _Odx2DEFRWM 1650380117
_NVz9nI7tf0 _rf0YjTVVK4 1663047964
_Odx2DEFRWM _UdUEF1CwRA 1481228895
_rf0YjTVVK4 _yi4N5b9sTU 1538420398
_UdUEF1CwRA --a2aRXEiG0 1528158581
_yi4N5b9sTU --watQ-FJZU 1568043561
--a2aRXEiG0 --X7T-oD8ZM 1650386074
--watQ-FJZU -07nlp8Y92c 1564659678
--X7T-oD8ZM -56SsUGegFY 1594058908
```

Comment: Can you share a spreadsheet sample with data?

Comment: sorry not sure how exactly other than copy and paste and placed a snippet in the message above; will try an attachment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the values in column N next to the appropriate values in column C, for each value in column C which is present in column M:

```
=ArrayFormula({tocol(C2:C,1),xlookup(tocol(C2:C,1),tocol(M2:M,1),tocol(N2:N,1),"not found")})
```

Comment: Thank you for your response; where exactly do I enter this formula?

Comment: Thank you; got this to work. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=XLOOKUP(
    C2,
    $M$2:$M,
    $N$2:$N,
    ””,0,1)
```

Enter the above in cell `D2`, then drag the formula all the way down.

This will look for `C2` in `M2`down to however long M2 ends up being, and if a match is found returns the corresponding value in column `N`.

If no match is found it returns an empty string, `””`.

The `0` means it looks for an exact match.

The `1` means it starts looking at the list from top to bottom when evaluating.

These last 2 arguments are not required.

**ADVANCED SOLUTION**
If you want to avoid dragging the formula all the way down manually you can try entering the below in `D2` and it will automatically flow all the way down:

```
=BYROW(C2:C,LAMBDA(r,IF(r=“”,””,
  XLOOKUP(
    r,
    $M$2:$M,
    $N$2:$N,
    ””,0,1))))
```

*Note: the line returns & indentation above is for legibility only and not required, but copy/pasting the above formula should work as is without changes.*

Comment: Thank you for your response; where exactly do I enter this formula?

Comment: @vbNewbie Enter the formula in `D2` If you want the values from column `N` to appear immediately to the right of the values in `C`. Just updated my answer to clarify, good question!

Comment: Thank you; appreciate it. I ended using the solution below which worked perfectly. Wish I could accept your answer too.

Comment: No worries—glad you got an answer :)